# Linked Lists and structs

Tags: c, list, linked-list, malloc

I'm working on a school project and I'm trying to understand doubly linked lists and structs a bit better. Currently, I'm trying to implement a function, one that creates a new linked list. Because I think I can work from there.

```
typedef struct ListItem {
    struct ListItem *previousItem; //pointer to previous item, NULL if first list item
    struct ListItem *nextItem;     //pointer to next item, NULL if first list item
    void *data;                    //pointer to data
```

This is the struct for the doubly linked list I am trying to make. I know that a "void *" can hold a pointer to anything, also that I have to allocate any data stored in the list item.

```
/**
 * This function starts a new linked list. Given an allocated pointer to data it will    return a
 * pointer for a malloc()ed ListItem struct. If malloc() fails for any reason, then this function
 * returns NULL otherwise it should return a pointer to this new list item. data can be NULL.
 *
 * @param data The data to be stored in the first ListItem in this new list. Can be any valid 
 *             pointer value.
  * @return A pointer to the malloc()'d ListItem. May be NULL if an error occured.
 */

ListItem *NewList(void *data);
```

I know that malloc() allocates enough memory on the stack for use, so I think that in my function I have to malloc() *previousItem, *nextItem, and *data (which would be 6 bytes?) Other than that, to implement the function all I would do is copy the ListItem struct? The previous AND next item would be NULL pointers since it is the only item in the list, and the *data would be the input I think. Can anyone give me an idea of what my code would look like?

Comment: malloc allocates on the heap not the stack

Comment: malloc doesn't allocate memory on the stack, it allocates memory on the heap.

Comment: (probably just a typo) but don't forget to close that struct!

Comment: And using malloc is not necessarily. You can allocate you nodes on the stack and point it's members to each other.

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track.  Instead of using `6` as the argument to `malloc`, you could use `sizeof` to get the amount of memory that you need to allocate - for example:

```
ListItem *node = malloc(sizeof(ListItem));
```

After that the implementation is fairly trivial:

```
/* Make sure that allocation succeeded */
...
/* Assign the right values to previousItem and nextItem */
...
/* Assign the right value to data */
...
/* Return the pointer to the new list */
...
```

Someone else will probably submit the full function, but your english language description of what needs to happen is spot on (other than the whole heap vs. stack thing).

Comment: Thanks for the input! I'm flipping through my C book to try to figure how to write this :)

Comment: Looking at the history of questions you've asked on StackOverflow, I'd say you were using us to do your course work for you.  Regardless, I hope this helps.

Comment: Is there a better way for me to phrase my questions in the future as to not give that impression? My goal is to understand C as best I can to the point where I don't have to ask questions as much, but I'm at a point where you can tell me what code to use, but I won't understand it very well even after googling it. Are there any resources you can offer for C help in general? Thanks!

edit** I do bug my instructor and TAs frequently but they are only so free to answer my questions. I'd be lying if I said I wasn't having trouble in this course so I'd appreciate any help people can offer!

Comment: A big part of learning how to write code is to *try it*.  There are free compilers for every OS.  A good start would be to update your question with your current implementation of `NewList` and point out specific places where you are having problems or don't understand how to proceed.  If you truly don't know what to do beyond writing the function prototype, going back to your intro to C programming book would probably be a good start.